# Forcing HTTPS and non-www (except ONE directory)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, exception, mod-rewrite, https

To force any page on my domain to **https** AND also to a **non-www**-version I'm using this snippet in the .htaccess, which **is working fine**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But I also want an **exception** for the directory **/folder/subfolder/** *not to* use SSL/TLS, or at least that there is no automatically redirection to the https-version if I call with http. So it would be okay, if **/folder/subfolder/** is still available via https, but I just don't want to force it for some reason.

---

Actually I could find some snippets here and elsewhere, but not in a combination with the non-www-version in a generic way. So hopefully somebody can help me, that would be nice :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this single to achieve all the tasks:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/older/subfolder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay. I'm afraid, the directory will be redirected as well. I tried it with different ISPs, devices and browsers.

Comment: ok try my edited rule as **very first rule** and make sure `/older/subfolder/ ` doesn't have any other .htaccess.

Comment: That's it, I guess. Thank you very much!